# Cancellation token sometimes doesnt cancel HttpRequest

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

My client application makes http request to the server. If server takes longer than 10s to respond I want the request to timeout. If request took longer than 5s but succeeded I log the response time. Most of the time everything works just like i expect. But sometimes it doesnt. Application blocks for very long time after which my log message says, that "Request took: 00:01:20.1234567. Was cancelled? False" which means that token was not cancelled nor httpClient timeout applied. Sometimes its "Request took: 00:01:20.1234567. Was cancelled? True" which suggest that token was cancelled, but httpClient ignored it. What could be the reason for such behavior?

Im running aspnet core 2.2 application. Im making multiple concurrent http requests at the same time using single tcp connection. I tried setting timeout property on httpClient. I tried creating CancellationTokenSource and cancelling token myself. Most of the time application works as expected.

````
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyNamespace.MyClass
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient()
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        };

        public string SendRequest()
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            request.RequestUri = new Uri("mockMyUri");
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.Content = new StringContent("myContent");
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            var response = _httpClient.SendAsync(request, cts.Token).Result;
            stopwatch.Stop();
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                throw new Exception();
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            if (stopwatch.Elapsed > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
                Console.WriteLine($"Request took: {stopwatch.Elapsed}. Was cancelled? {cts.IsCancellationRequested}");
            return content;
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The `CancellationToken` and `CancellationTokenSource` are used for asynchronous operations. 
But your call to `_httpClient`, even though it's calling the `SendAsync`, is processing synchronously, because there's no `**await**` keyword, and you are using the `.Result` (this makes it wait for the result to be received).
Your function and call to _httpClient should be something like this:

```
public async Task<string> SendRequest() 
{
 ...
  var responseTask = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, cts.Token);
  var response = responseTask.Result;
 ...
 // and the same for content:
  var contentTask = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  return contentTask;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Unfortunately your suggested code didnt solved my issue. I ended up applying a workaround.